# How to write test cases for JSON API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec, render

I have written an api for topics controller which will do all the crud operations.I need to test the api using Rspec. For the index action i have written a test case for http status.Further i need to check weather the index page is rendered correctly.Topic Api controller for index action is like this:

```
class Api::V1::TopicsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @topics = Topic.all
    render json: @topics,status: 200
  end
end
```

Rspec for topic controller index action is:

```
RSpec.describe Api::V1::TopicsController do
describe "GET #index" do
before do
  get :index
end
it "returns http success" do
  expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  ////expect(response).to render_template(:index)
end
end
end
```

When run the testing it showing error message for the above line of code that i mentioned in comments.

```
Api::V1::TopicsController GET #index returns http success
 Failure/Error: expect(response).to render_template(:index)
   expecting <"index"> but rendering with <[]>
```

How to resolve it?
 error:

```
  TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer

0) Api::V1::TopicsController GET #index should return all the topics
   Failure/Error: expect(response_body['topics'].length).to eq(2)

   TypeError:
   no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

Comment: You should not be testing your `views` when you are controller is rendering `json` response . You should check for `response` status, also, make use of `stub` to `stub` your response and compare against your `request` and `expected response`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your API response for your controller actions, just a reference for your `index` action.

```
describe TopicsController do

  describe "GET 'index' " do

    it "should return a successful response" do
      get :index, format: :json
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
    end

    it "should return all the topics" do
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:topic, 2)
      get :index, format: :json
      expect(assigns[:topics].size).to eq 2
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: what does it mean create_list in your code

Comment: If you want to create an object multiple times, it's the same as `2.times {FactoryGirl.create(:topic)}`

Comment: When I run the tests that you provided it throwing error   "no implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Comment: Which line ? Can you update your OP with the errors ?

Comment: OP means what???

Comment: expect(response_body['topics'].length).to eq(2) it showing error on this line

Comment: _Original Poster_. Update your question with the error.

Comment: What is the output of `response_body` ?

Comment: I have updated my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179305/discussion-between-kedarnag-mukanahallipatna-and-praveen-r).